# Supercover line algorithm from corners instead of the square's center?

Tags: 2d, algorithm, grid, line-of-sight

I need to check whether a cell in a 2D grid is visible to the starting cell. I'm currently using amit's supercover line algorithm, this one https://www.redblobgames.com/grids/line-drawing.html#supercover

The algorithm works but I need  the cells that are intersected by the top-left corner-to-corner line instead of the center-to-center.

This shows what I mean:

- The green square is the start point and red is the end point
- The white dots represents the cells that are visited by the line drawing algorithm I'm using
- I want to get the cells that are intersected by the blue line. It's drew from the top-left corner of the start cell to the top-left corner of the end cell.

[image: https://i.imgur.com/BZPLKOr.png]

This is my implementation of the amit's algorithm in gdscript

```
func _line_of_sight(p0, p1):
    var dx = p1.x - p0.x
    var dy = p1.y - p0.y
    
    var sx = 1 if dx > 0 else -1
    var sy = 1 if dy > 0 else -1
    
    var p = Vector2(p0.x, p0.y)
    _points.append(p)
    
    var x = 0
    var y = 0
    var nx = abs(dx)
    var ny = abs(dy)
    
    var result = true
    var blocked_cells = _tilemap.get_used_cells()
    
    while x < nx or y < ny:
        var px = (1+2*x) * ny
        var py = (1+2*y) * nx
        
        if px == py:
            p.x += sx
            p.y += sy
            x += 1
            y += 1
            
        elif px < py:
            p.x += sx
            x += 1
        else:
            p.y += sy
            y += 1
            
        if blocked_cells.has(p):
            result = false
            
        _points.append(p)
        
    return result
```

I've also tried Bresenham's line algorithm and the Bresenham supercover modification, [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bresenham%27s_line_algorithm) and [this](http://eugen.dedu.free.fr/projects/bresenham/), as well as [this](http://playtechs.blogspot.com/2007/03/raytracing-on-grid.html), but none did the trick

Any insight would be appreciated - thanks in advance!

Comment: If you're willing to use floating point, then you can move the start and endpoints of the line to any location you want in their respective cells and [trace the ray between them with this](http://www.cse.yorku.ca/~amana/research/grid.pdf)

Comment: That did it, thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution was to use "A Fast Voxel Traversal Algorithm for Ray Tracing", as suggested by DMGregor, to trace a ray from/to "world" position instead of a grid cell's coordinate. I implemented the algorithm based on this site: https://www.flipcode.com/archives/Raytracing_Topics_Techniques-Part_4_Spatial_Subdivisions.shtml

[image]

Some of the other links I visited during my research:

- https://theshoemaker.de/2016/02/ray-casting-in-2d-grids/
- [http://www.cse.yorku.ca/~amana/research/grid.pdf](http://www.cse.yorku.ca/%7Eamana/research/grid.pdf)
- https://github.com/francisengelmann/fast_voxel_traversal
- https://www.shadertoy.com/view/XddcWn
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11694886/traverse-a-2-5d-grid